# Mapping a table to multiple subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a table `NOTE` that is mapped into two two Java classes `UserNote` and `SaleNote`:

```
abstract class AbstractNote {}

class UserNote extends AbstractNote {}

class SaleNote extends AbstractNote {}
```

in my hibernate `hbm` file for `AbstractNote`I used a `discriminator` value:

```
<discriminator column="NOTE_TYPE_CODE" type="string" force="true"/>
```

and for each subclass, in the `hbm` file: `discriminator-value="USER"` and `discriminator-value="SALE"`.

My question is, is it possible to have a general class that maps all notes?

Answer (score 0):

if your db has only `NOTE` table, having a single entity mapping the entire table is straightforward... just implement a concrete class `Note` and have `NOTE_TYPE_CODE` mapped as property instead of discriminator

```
@Entity
public class Note 
{
    @Column(name = "NOTE_TYPE_CODE")
    private String noteTypeCode;

    ... other columns/properties/joins/collections ...

    public String getNoteTypeCode()
    {
        return noteTypeCode;
    }

    public void setNoteTypeCode(String noteTypeCode)
    {
        this.noteTypeCode = noteTypeCode;
    }

    ... other getters/setters ...
}
```